# Literally-Connecting Wall

Tags: grid-deduction, connect-wall

This puzzle is a variant on the well-known connecting wall puzzles. May contain traces of grid deduction and happy stars

Rules:

- Your goal is to fill all the empty squares in the main grid (left) with either path tiles or happy star tiles (right).
- Each word/phrase must be connected to a happy star, either directly (orthogonally adjacent) or via one or more path tiles.
- Each happy star must be similarly connected to four words/phrases that are thematically related (e.g. names of UK Prime Ministers)

Good luck!
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the categories:

> PSE 100K users:
>
> Gareth McCaughan
>
> Stiv
>
> Deusovi
>
> Hexomino

> Only Connect Egyptian heiroglyphs:
>
> (Twisted) Flax
>
> (Eye of) Horus
>
> (Two) Reeds
>
> Water

> PSE tags:
>
> No computers
>
> Lateral thinking
>
> Sudoku
>
> Cryptic clues

> Quiz/Game shows:
>
> 1 vs 100
>
> Only Connect
>
> Jeopardy!
>
> Pointless

> [Synonym of Happy] [anagram of Star]:
>
> Joyful Arts
>
> Cheerful Tars
>
> Glad Tsar
>
> Smiling Rats

Then the grid:

> [image]
>
>  The solve path was fairly straightforward, starting with a star in the top-left corner for the Happy Star group. Then the tags group which are mostly at the bottom of the grid. And the rest was mostly forced.

Comment: Well done. If this concept is considered sufficiently fun I'm sure there's plenty of scope for more challenging puzzles :)

Comment: @happystar I found it fun. I'm wondering if it's possible to have a puzzle where there are overlaps and red herrings that lead to multiple solutions in the groups, but only one of them leads to a solvable grid.